# JavaScript Event implementation to Closure based Object

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a Object based on some closure, and want to implement event scheme here:

```
var class1 = function(val1)
{
    var val = val1;    
//------ want to call a method of Object of class1--------
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        self.onEvent();

    }, 1000);
//----------------  
    return {
        f1: function()
        {
            return val;
        },
        onEvent: function()
        {
            console.log('not implemented yet. Override');
        }
    };
};

var obj1 = class1(5);
console.log(obj1.f1()); //5

obj1.onEvent(); //not implemented yet. Override   
obj1.onEvent = function()
{
    console.log('event fired');
}
```

got error, and I know the reason, and I need a solution:

```
5
not implemented yet. Override

/....../app.js:9
        self.onEvent();
             ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onEvent'
```

**It is possible if this bind with addEventListener scheme like this:**

(The idea based on
[Implementing events in my own object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978311/implementing-events-in-my-own-object)
)

```
var class2 = function()
{
    var _this = this;
    _this.events = {};
    var fireEvent = function(name, args)
    {
        if (!_this.events.hasOwnProperty(name)) return;
        if (!args || !args.length) args = [];  
        var evs = _this.events[name];
        var l = evs.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            evs[i].apply(null, args);
        }
    };   
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        fireEvent('testEvent', ['hello'])
    }, 1000);   
    return {
        addEventListener: function(name, handler)
        {
            if (_this.events.hasOwnProperty(name))
                _this.events[name].push(handler);
            else
                _this.events[name] = [handler];
        }
    };
};  
var obj2 = class2();   
obj2.addEventListener('testEvent',
    function(data)
    {
        console.log('event fired: ' + data);
    });
```

`event fired: hello`

However, I prefer not to use addEventListener but .onEvent() scheme.

Is it possible? Perhaps it is possible using call/apply.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first block of code, you are returning an object, which is different from `this` or `self`.

You don't necessarily have to return `this` in your constructors but you should assign your functions on the returned object. If you create a variable for the object you want to return, you can use it in your `setTimeout` callback like so:

```
var class1 = function(val1)
{
    var val = val1;    

    var obj = {
        f1: function()
        {
            return val;
        },
        onEvent: function()
        {
            console.log('not implemented yet. Override');
        }
    };

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        obj.onEvent();

    }, 1000);

    return obj;
};
```

For extra style points, you might want to capitalize the name of your constructors (and perhaps use `new` to instantiate them to make things clearer to your readers).

Comment: Yes,sure. Matt, you are absolutely right! I somehow felt this solution, but could not find this clear one so far. Thank you very much!