# Is it possible to write Closure based Object with Node require('util').inherits()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

Previously, I asked here

[JavaScript Event implementation to Closure based Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108540/javascript-event-implementation-to-closure-based-object)

Now, I wonder if this style can be employed with with Node require('util').inherits().

The target code would be

https://github.com/kenokabe/WebSocketStream/blob/master/main.js

Here there is

1. Object
2. require('util').inherits()
3. Prototype Override methods

and I wonder if possible to rewrite code on Closure based Object.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? Where do you want another closure, don't you already have one?

Comment: Please post [the relevant parts of] your code here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: And what exactly is a "Closure based Object"?