# addEventListener on custom object

Tags: javascript

```
var elem =Object.create(CustomEvent.prototype)
     elem.arr = [1,2,3];

     elem.addEventListener("added_item", function(event) {
      elem.push(10);
      console.log( event.detail.name );
     }, false);

     var event = new CustomEvent("added_item", {
      detail: { name: "Вася" }
     });

     elem.dispatchEvent(event);
     elem.dispatchEvent(event);
     elem.dispatchEvent(event);
     elem.dispatchEvent(event);


     console.log(elem);
```

> index.html:40 Uncaught TypeError: elem.addEventListener is not a
>   function

CustomEvent works only with HTMLElements ?

**What 's alternative ?**

Comment: Event listeners are on DOM elements, not events.

Comment: `CustomEvent` represents a single instance of an event (e.g. a click, a mouseover, etc.). Instances of `CustomEvent` don't have an `addEventListener` method because they don't generate events; they _are_ events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing events in my own object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978311/implementing-events-in-my-own-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need `elem` to be an event *target*, not an event. AFAIK, there isn't a way to use the built-in `EventTarget` for your own purposes, but MDN provides a [simple implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) for `EventTarget` that you can instantiate and use for yourself:

```js
var MyEventTarget = function() {
  this.listeners = {};
};

MyEventTarget.prototype.listeners = null;
MyEventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, callback) {
  if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
    this.listeners[type] = [];
  }
  this.listeners[type].push(callback);
};

MyEventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, callback) {
  if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
    return;
  }
  var stack = this.listeners[type];
  for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (stack[i] === callback){
      stack.splice(i, 1);
      return this.removeEventListener(type, callback);
    }
  }
};

MyEventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
  if (!(event.type in this.listeners)) {
    return;
  }
  var stack = this.listeners[event.type];
  event.target = this;
  for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
      stack[i].call(this, event);
  }
};

var elem = new MyEventTarget()
elem.arr = [1, 2, 3];

elem.addEventListener("added_item", function(event) {
  elem.arr.push(10);
  console.log(event.detail.name);
}, false);

var event = new CustomEvent("added_item", {
  detail: {
    name: "Вася"
  }
});

elem.dispatchEvent(event);
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
elem.dispatchEvent(event);


console.log(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements expose API with methods like `addEvenetListent` or `dispatchEvent` but those methods are not defined on `CustomEvent` prototype.

Comment: To nitpick, other objects have this method. e.g XMLHttpRequest, FileReader, AudioContext ...